# Breadcrumbs error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to use the breadcrumbs by `davejamesmiller`

In the `breadcrumbs.php` file which is in the same directory as of `route.php` I have setup up this:

```
<?php

Breadcrumbs::register('courses', function($breadcrumbs) {
    $breadcrumbs->push('Courses', route('courses')); });
```

and in the `route.php` I have:

```
Route::get('/courses', 'CoursesController@index');
```

and in the `courses.index` I called the breadcrumbs like this:

`{{ Breadcrumbs::render('courses') }}`

But I'm getting an error as follows:

`Route [courses] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\lc2\laravel\app\views\courses\index.blade.php)`

What might be the problem? I cant seem to figure out. I already have the route set for the `courses`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have to use laravel named routes - [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes) , also in github repo [readme](https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs)

```
Route::get('/courses', ['uses' => 'CoursesController@index', 'as' => 'courses']);
```